# how to use retrofit request two api

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-java2

I want check the result from Api1, if the result is 200 or "success",than request the Api2.

my bad code:

```
RetrofitService.getApis().api1()
         .filter(new Predicate<Result1>() {
        @Override
        public boolean test(Result1 result1) throws Exception {
            return result1.code==200;
        }
    })
     .flatMap(new Function<Result1>, ObservableSource<Result2>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<Result2> apply(Result1  result1 ) throws Exception {
                    return RetrofitService.getApis().api2(result1.data);
                }
            })
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<Result2>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Result2 value) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });
```

but,Observer will never be call when result1.code!=200.

Comment: Well, of course - that's what the `filter` does. What would you like to happen instead?

Comment: I would like to call Observer#onError(Throwable ) when code! = 200@david.mihola

Comment: The you could just drop the `filter` and instead inside your `flatMap`: `if (result1.code == 200) {<what you are doing now> } else { return Observable.error(<some Throwable>)}`

Comment: thank you！and.......I have the another problem....  I want to use 'Observable.timer' to hide view delay, how to refresh the delay time?